# Tensorboard: None Scalar Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, data-science, tensorboard

I'm currently struggling with a non-trivial scalar in tensorboard. The only peculiarity is that sometimes it cannot be defined (i.e. it has **None** value).

I would like to see it on my tensorboard and don't find the following workarounds acceptable:

1. Simply *don't write the value*. If you do so, you won't have a "gap" or any other noticeable mark on your graph (i.e. you won't see the value is missing if you have lots of data)
2. Simply write *0*. *0* and *None* values of the metric have different meaning
3. Write a predefined value. This is somehow acceptable, but it will influence the smoothed value and is not particularly elegant.

The current tensorboard API does not let me achieve what I want, so I'm all ears to your workaround suggestions.

One of the possible solutions might be to have the shape of the tick to be different, like in the following image from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146614/tensorboard-plot-training-and-validation-losses-on-the-same-graph), but I can't find the API to achieve that.

[image: Desired Look of None values]

Thank You for Your time, looking forward to Your replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write `numpy.nan` and it should meet all your needs:

1. It won't affect the smoothed value.
2. The mark will be different.