# Is there a way to plot training and validation losses on the same graph with HuggingFace TrainerAPI?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, tensorboard

I am fine-tuning a HuggingFace transformer model (PyTorch version), using the HF Seq2SeqTrainingArguments & Seq2SeqTrainer, and I want to display in Tensorboard the train and validation losses (in the same chart).

As far as I understand in order to plot the two losses together I need to use the SummaryWriter. The HF Callbacks documenation describes a TensorBoardCallback function that can receive a tb_writer argument:

https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.21.1/en/main_classes/callback#transformers.integrations.TensorBoardCallback

However, I cannot figure out what is the right way to use it, if it is even supposed to be used with the Trainer API.

My code looks something like this:

```
args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir=output_dir,
    evaluation_strategy='epoch',
    learning_rate= 1e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    save_total_limit=3,
    num_train_epochs=num_train_epochs,
    predict_with_generate=True,
    logging_steps=logging_steps,
    report_to='tensorboard',
    push_to_hub=False,  
)

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model,
    args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_train_data,
    eval_dataset=tokenized_val_data,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)
```

I would assume I should include the callback to TensorBoard in the trainer, e.g.,

```
callbacks = [TensorBoardCallback(tb_writer=tb_writer)]
```

but I cannot find a comprehensive example of how to use/what to import to use it.

I also found this feature request on GitHub,

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/4020

but no example of use, so I am confused...

Any insight will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

The only way I know of to plot two values on the same `TensorBoard` graph is to use two separate `SummaryWriter`s with the same root directory. For example, the logging directories might be: `log_dir/train` and `log_dir/eval`.

This approach is used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55863830/1349673) but for `TensorFlow` instead of `pytorch`.

In order to do this with the  `Trainer` API a custom callback is needed that takes two `SummaryWriter`s. Here is the code for my custom callback `CombinedTensorBoardCallback`, that I made by modifying the code for `TensorBoardCallback`:

```
import os
from transformers.integrations import TrainerCallback, is_tensorboard_available

def custom_rewrite_logs(d, mode):
    new_d = {}
    eval_prefix = "eval_"
    eval_prefix_len = len(eval_prefix)
    test_prefix = "test_"
    test_prefix_len = len(test_prefix)
    for k, v in d.items():
        if mode == 'eval' and k.startswith(eval_prefix):
            if k[eval_prefix_len:] == 'loss':
                new_d["combined/" + k[eval_prefix_len:]] = v
        elif mode == 'test' and k.startswith(test_prefix):
            if k[test_prefix_len:] == 'loss':
                new_d["combined/" + k[test_prefix_len:]] = v
        elif mode == 'train':
            if k == 'loss':
                new_d["combined/" + k] = v
    return new_d


class CombinedTensorBoardCallback(TrainerCallback):
    """
    A [`TrainerCallback`] that sends the logs to [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard).
    Args:
        tb_writer (`SummaryWriter`, *optional*):
            The writer to use. Will instantiate one if not set.
    """

    def __init__(self, tb_writers=None):
        has_tensorboard = is_tensorboard_available()
        if not has_tensorboard:
            raise RuntimeError(
                "TensorBoardCallback requires tensorboard to be installed. Either update your PyTorch version or"
                " install tensorboardX."
            )
        if has_tensorboard:
            try:
                from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter  # noqa: F401

                self._SummaryWriter = SummaryWriter
            except ImportError:
                try:
                    from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter

                    self._SummaryWriter = SummaryWriter
                except ImportError:
                    self._SummaryWriter = None
        else:
            self._SummaryWriter = None
        self.tb_writers = tb_writers

    def _init_summary_writer(self, args, log_dir=None):
        log_dir = log_dir or args.logging_dir
        if self._SummaryWriter is not None:
            self.tb_writers = dict(train=self._SummaryWriter(log_dir=os.path.join(log_dir, 'train')),
                                   eval=self._SummaryWriter(log_dir=os.path.join(log_dir, 'eval')))

    def on_train_begin(self, args, state, control, **kwargs):
        if not state.is_world_process_zero:
            return

        log_dir = None

        if state.is_hyper_param_search:
            trial_name = state.trial_name
            if trial_name is not None:
                log_dir = os.path.join(args.logging_dir, trial_name)

        if self.tb_writers is None:
            self._init_summary_writer(args, log_dir)

        for k, tbw in self.tb_writers.items():
            tbw.add_text("args", args.to_json_string())
            if "model" in kwargs:
                model = kwargs["model"]
                if hasattr(model, "config") and model.config is not None:
                    model_config_json = model.config.to_json_string()
                    tbw.add_text("model_config", model_config_json)
            # Version of TensorBoard coming from tensorboardX does not have this method.
            if hasattr(tbw, "add_hparams"):
                tbw.add_hparams(args.to_sanitized_dict(), metric_dict={})

    def on_log(self, args, state, control, logs=None, **kwargs):
        if not state.is_world_process_zero:
            return

        if self.tb_writers is None:
            self._init_summary_writer(args)

        for tbk, tbw in self.tb_writers.items():
            logs_new = custom_rewrite_logs(logs, mode=tbk)
            for k, v in logs_new.items():
                if isinstance(v, (int, float)):
                    tbw.add_scalar(k, v, state.global_step)
                else:
                    logger.warning(
                        "Trainer is attempting to log a value of "
                        f'"{v}" of type {type(v)} for key "{k}" as a scalar. '
                        "This invocation of Tensorboard's writer.add_scalar() "
                        "is incorrect so we dropped this attribute."
                    )
            tbw.flush()

    def on_train_end(self, args, state, control, **kwargs):
        for tbw in self.tb_writers.values():
            tbw.close()
        self.tb_writers = None
```

If you want to combine train and eval for other metrics besides the loss then `custom_rewrite_logs` should be modified accordingly.

As usual, the callback goes in the `Trainer` constructor. In my test example it was:

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model=rnn,
    args=train_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=validation_dataset,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    callbacks=[CombinedTensorBoardCallback]
)
```

Also you might want to remove the default `TensorBoardCallback` or else in addition to the combined loss graph, the training loss and validation loss will both appear separately as it does by default.

```
trainer.remove_callback(TensorBoardCallback)
```

Here is the resulting `TensorBoard` view:

[image]

Comment: Thnx for the answer, I have no trouble outputting events for Tensorboard, I want to output train and validation loss on the ***same*** plot (Tensorboard by default produces, among other, 2 separate plots, one for the train loss and one for validation). I assumed that to do this I will have to tweak the tb_writer and pass it to as an argument to a TensorBoardCallback. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Oh, I did not read your question carefully. I have edit the title of this question to make it clear what you asking about. I hope my new answer helps. Btw, I do not know if it is even possible by tweaking a single `tb_writer`, and instead I used two.

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty simple. You mention it in the "Seq2SeqTrainingArguments". There is no need to define it explicitly in the "Seq2SeqTrainer" function.

```
model_arguments = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(output_dir= "./best_model/",
                                        num_train_epochs = EPOCHS, 
                                        overwrite_output_dir= True, 
                                        do_train= True, 
                                        do_eval= True, 
                                        do_predict= True, 
                                        auto_find_batch_size= True, 
                                        evaluation_strategy = 'epoch',
                                        warmup_steps = 10000, 
                                        logging_dir = "./log_files/", 
                                        disable_tqdm = False, 
                                        load_best_model_at_end = True, 
                                        save_strategy= 'epoch', 
                                        save_total_limit = 1, 
                                        per_device_eval_batch_size= BATCH_SIZE, 
                                        per_device_train_batch_size= BATCH_SIZE, 
                                        predict_with_generate=True, 
                                        report_to='wandb',
                                        run_name="rober_based_encoder_decoder_text_summarisation"
                                        
                                        )
```

meanwhile you can have other callbacks:

```
early_stopping = EarlyStoppingCallback(early_stopping_patience= 5, 
                                    early_stopping_threshold= 0.001)
```

Then you pass the arguments and callbacks as the list through the trainer arguments:

```
trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(model = model, 
                        compute_metrics= compute_metrics,
                        args= model_arguments, 
                        train_dataset= Train, 
                        eval_dataset= Val, 
                        tokenizer=tokenizer, 
                        callbacks= [early_stopping, ]
                        )
```

Train the model. Make sure you log into the wandb before training

```
trainer.train()
```